# Deriving an inequality related to an induced matrix norm

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, matrix-norms

Suppose we have the induced matrix norm for an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix $A$ given by,

\begin{equation*}
|||A|||_{\infty,h} = \max_{1\leq i \leq N}\left(\sum_{j=1}^N |A_{ij}|\right).
\end{equation*}

where $h = \frac{1}{N+1}$ and $i=1,2,3....N$ and $j=1,2,3...M$ and $N, M \in \mathbb{N}$. Additionally, suppose we have the vector $U$ given by,
\begin{equation*}
U^j = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1^j\\ 
u^j_2\\ 
\vdots\\ 
u^j_N
\end{pmatrix}~\in\mathbb{R}^N.
\end{equation*}
where $u_i^j$ is just the discrete solution to a governing problem. Additionally, we define the infinity norm as such,
\begin{equation*}
||U||_{\infty,h} = \max_{1\leq i \leq N} |U_i|.
\end{equation*}

The following inequality is true,
\begin{equation*}
||AU||_{\infty,h}\leq|||A|||_{\infty,h}  ||U||_{\infty,h},
\end{equation*}
however, I have no idea how one can obtain this result.

Comment: the dependence in $h$ seems useless, is it?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is useless in this question given here but comes into play later so I thought I might include it in the question.

Comment: If I get it, you want to prove that 
$$\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}=\max_{i}\sum_j |A_{ij}|$$

Comment: Here is a proof: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.709.1809&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.